# How to convert ESRI .prj WKT string to Proj4 string WITHOUT GDAL

Tags: shapefile, proj, well-known-text

ESRI shapefiles include a .prj file containing CRS information in Well-Known Text (WKT) format.
I'm developing a software in which I need to **systematically** read shapefiles' CRS information, convert it to a Proj4 string, and feed Proj4 with it.

The software I'm developing **can not** have dependencies on GDAL.

So, how can I systematically convert/parse a WKT string from a .prj file into a Proj4 string? Is there any direct mapping between the tags?

Alternatively, instead of converting to a Proj4 string, finding the corresponding EPSG code would also be acceptable.

Comment: The .prj file isn't strictly in WKT format, so you might be specifying a wrong source.

Comment: Can't you take the morphtoesri part of GDAL into your software? That is the part that makes the conversion and it is MIT licensed.

Comment: Somehow use spatialreference.org and/or ask the site creators if they used something other than GDAL or PROJ4 itself.

Comment: @Vince What other formats can it have? I have never seen (or heard of) a .prj file that wasn't in WKT. But I also haven't found any clear specifications...

Comment: @user30184 This may be the solution, however the morphFromESRI function converts the WKT text to a gdal internal format which I'm not familiar with. I was looking for a more straightforward conversion to Proj4.
But I may have to resort to some kind of reverse engineering of that function, though.
PS: I think you meant morphFromESRI :)

Comment: Yes, morphFromESRI or perhaps even importFromESRI https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogr_srs_esri.cpp.

Comment: The other way to do it is by using ESRI SDK eg. .NET one:

var wkt = File.ReadAllText(projPath);
var sp = new SpatialReference(wkt);
var epsg = sp.Wkid;

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/geometry/SpatialReference.html